# (webpack) library version conflicts, npm vs bower

Tags: javascript, npm, bundle, bower, webpack

Getting started with [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), and while not explicitly stated, a lot of examples and starter kits use NPM over Bower for managing their front-end libraries. Further, recent articles suggest we [don't need](https://gofore.com/ohjelmistokehitys/stop-using-bower/) Bower [any more](https://medium.com/@nickheiner/why-my-team-uses-npm-instead-of-bower-eecfe1b9afcb#.e23sfluqi). Maybe I'm using the wrong workflow, but I don't see how NPM can fully replace Bower when you're using libraries with shared dependencies.

Consider a project that uses jQuery and two jquery plugins. The first requires 2.2.0 and the other requires 2.0.3.

When webpack creates the bundle, two versions of jquery exist!?! Yes, the DedupePlugin can be used to remove the duplicates, but I can't find any documentation regarding which version it keeps. Seems like it just keeps the first one it encounters. Therefore, if I want to force a specific version, I need to npm install jquery and add a `resolve.alias`.

On the other hand, with Bower, I know exactly which version is being bundled. And should a conflict arise, it tells me. I can investigate the conflict and specify the appropriate version.

What am I missing? How are you using Webpack with front-end libraries? What is your workflow?

Comment: ah this is a common probem apparently webpack uses its own jquery, what I did was add `var $ = require('jquery'); window.jQuery = $; window.$ = $;` inside a webpack config so they all share the same window jquery file. I think there's a duplicate question here in stackoverflow I can't find it however.

Comment: @PauAI I used jquery as an example. Consider an app that uses backbone.marionette and any number of backbone plugins. Marionette depends on bb 1.2.3. Plugin xyz depends on bb 1.2.0. Same version conflict.

Comment: Ouch that would be a pickle, sorry I have no answer for that. normally I keep all my scripts up to date and refactor if there are any deprecated functions